# How to run a ajax button?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, button

I'm designing a button to insert data into a database using ajax, but i could not find the source of the problem to why the code is not working. Each button that appears on the screen has value in it, once the user clicks on it, the value will be sent to a database and be stored.

This is my code for the button,

```html
<?php
require 'dbfunction.php';
require 'checkLoginStatus.php';


$con = getDbConnect(); // invoke the getDbConnect() function to get a database connection
$day = date("l");

$adminid = $staff_information["staff_Id"]; // retrieve admin email 

if (!mysqli_connect_errno()) { // connection to database is successful
    $sqlQueryStr = "SELECT BI.timetable_Id, BI.academicInstitution, BI.startTime, BI.endTime, BI.day " .
            "FROM timetableschedule BI " .
            "WHERE BI.staffID ='" . $adminid . "' AND BI.day='" . $day . "' " .
            "ORDER BY BI.timetable_Id";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlQueryStr);  // execute the SQL query<dl></dl>

    while ($schedule = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $scheduleRegList[$schedule['timetable_Id']] = $schedule;
    }
    mysqli_close($con);

    if (isset($scheduleRegList)) { // studentList exist
        foreach ($scheduleRegList as $timetable_Id => $key) {
            echo '<input type="button" name="' . $timetable_Id . '" class="scheduleReg" value="';
            echo $key['academicInstitution'] . "<br />";
            echo $key['startTime'] . "-" . $key['endTime'] . "hrs<br />";
            echo '"></input>';
        }
        echo "</select><br /><br/ >";
    } else {
        echo "no record.";
    }
} else {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>

<?php 
if (isset($scheduleRegList)) {
?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".scheduleReg").click(scheduleReg);
    });
            
    function scheduleReg(){
        var data = new Object();
        data.timetable_Id = this.name;
        $.post("register.php",data, loadModule);
    }
</script> 
<?php
}
?>
```

And this is my register.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();

require 'dbfunction.php';

$timetable_Id = $_POST['timetable_Id']; // get module code from $_POST

$con = getDbConnect(); // invoke the getDbConnect() function to get a database connection

if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) { // connection to database is successful
    $sqlQueryStr =
            "INSERT INTO report (staff_Id) " . "VALUES ('$timetable_Id')";

    mysqli_query($con, $sqlQueryStr);    
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: show the resultant html. Seem to have a closing `<select>` tag with no opening tag. Have you inspected the actual requests in browser dev tools network? Are they being made? Is data sent what is expected?

Comment: does your console log show the ajax call was made? does your value show in the ajax call?

Comment: @Sean I got this from the console log "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
arraybtn.php:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: You don't have jquery loaded ? or cache error .. clear your cookies ..

Comment: I just realized that i forgot to add in my jquery, but now i get a different error "Uncaught ReferenceError: loadModule is not defined"

Comment: Please edit your question to include information on what the problem is. "Not working" is not a description of a problem.